# LCD monitor reports incorrect maximum resolution

Tags: multiple-monitors, resolution, nvidia-graphics-card, lcd

I have four 20" Planar 2010M LCD monitors with a maximum resolution of 1600 x 1200 connected to two nVidia video cards (8600 GT and 7600 GS).  I'm running Windows Server 2003 x86.

Recently, two of the monitors have started mis-reporting their maximum resolution as 1280 x 1024.  When this first happened, I used nVidia's Custom Resolutions feature to force the monitors back to 1600 x 1200.  Yesterday, however, I upgraded nVidia's video card driver, and ever since, I cannot get the DVI one back to 1600 x 1200.  When I add the custom resolution in nVidia's control panel, if I set either the width or the height to even a single pixel more than 1280 x 1024, nothing changes when I click Test (the monitor doesn't even flash black, although after 15 seconds, it flashes black and doesn't change).  After adding

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Is there anything I can do about it?

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked with the monitor manufacturer to see if they have any drivers/ini's for the monitors.  If they are available, it will help your video card identify them correctly.